# How to signout from foursquare using its api in xcode?

Tags: xcode, api, foursquare

i am using foursquare api in xcode.

what i do is: using its api i get authenticated on forsquare successfully , in order to signout i dont see any api documentation there.

i am using following code but not working:

```
- (void)logout {
    oAuth4sq=nil;
    oAuth4sq.oauth_token=nil;
    oAuth4sq.oauth_token_secret=nil;
    [oAuth4sq forget];
    [oAuth4sq save];
    //[self resetUi];
}
```

any one guide me how to signout user or kill session of authenticated api? so that i could open a sign in screen in webview instead of getting same user already authenticated there.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for an app to terminate an auth key -- the user needs to revoke access via https://foursquare.com/settings/connections.

If want users to ensure that users explicitly sign in each time via the auth flow, use /authorize instead of /authenticate for the OAuth URL. /authorize always asks the user to authorize the app, where as /authenticate auto-redirects if the logged in user has already authorized the app.